# How do I stop Javascript execution? And all timers? (How to stop a function from polling - or monkeypatching it)

Tags: javascript

I want to stop a script from executing, similar to what the Esc key does in Firefox. It stops all Javascript from running on that page as well as all gif animations.

Is there a function I could call which would stop everything?

Comment: Because a part of the JavaScript which I have no control over is polling the server which makes Chrome flash/change the reload button, which makes for an annoying user experience. Id like to disable the polling since its not necessary after _my_ code runs. Im not allowed to change/touch code outside my module. Yep. Management at its finest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how the offending module is organized, perhaps you can monkey-patch it without having to change its source code.

For example, if the annoying polling function is global or namespaced you can try to replace it with a useless stub:

```
//save the old version of the function, in case
//we need to restore it afterwards
var nasty_function = His.Namespaced.Evil.func;

//put our own stub in place
His.Namespaced.Evil.func = function(what, args, it , should, receive){
    return somthing_that_signals_a_failed_poll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing like that. And there's also no real reason for it: you write the code, you can make it stop doing things if you want to.

Plus: if there were such a function that stopped **all JS activity**... how would you make it start up again?

Comment: Thats a good question, but I wouldnt. Just top the damn thing. Firefox can do it, other browsers should too.